# call mvc action from console application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

i want call mvc4 action from console application

action url = xyz
action parameters (Datetime lastUpdateTime)

Here is my Code

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StoryBoardSchedulerJobUrl"]);
            webRequest.Method = "POST";
            var data = string.Format("lastUpdateTime={0}", Uri.EscapeDataString(DateTime.Now.ToString()));
            StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream());
            requestWriter.Write(data);
            requestWriter.Close();

            var response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
```

Comment: The new HttpClient object simplifies making requests. You might want to check that out.

Answer (score 0):

1. Encode your data (UTF8)
2. Specifiy the `ContentType` and `ContentLength`
3. Write the encoded data into the request stream

#### Sample

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StoryBoardSchedulerJobUrl"]);
webRequest.Method = "POST";
var data = string.Format("lastUpdateTime={0}", Uri.EscapeDataString(DateTime.Now.ToString()));
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
webRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream());
requestWriter.Write(byteArray);
requestWriter.Close();

var response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
```